# Angular 2 how to store properties

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, properties-file

So, I wonder what is best approach for storing properties data like url/username/password for backend services. I have few environemnts, angular-cli provide environment..ts files, but it is kinda not smart if we will put there password for prod environment. So propably I should make some external files? For backend(spring boot), we are using application.properties files, it is built in mechanism, what about Angular2/angular-cli do they have any built in mechanism ? It should be common problem with many solutions but I cannot find anything.

Edit: We are talking about some REST services that are behind only basic auth of server, those RESTs are unauthenticated. Doesn't matter who is calling them I just want to secure them from random calls from internet.

Comment: You are supposed to check the credentials on your backend, not your front-end. So you don't have to store any credentials on the front-end. But it doesn't matter the way, if you want to store credentials on the front-end, your users will see it (if they want to and have time & patience). And in my opinion, the environment files are great to store this kind of data.

Comment: Everything you do in angular will end up on the user's computer. It's not recommended to place production environment passwords in the front-end where anyone can see it. Your alternative is to use tokens distributed by your back-end or have a back-end that will use the password for you.

Comment: Ok so maybe I will add some details. This case is kinda exception, my all services use tokens, but 2 services are unauthorized so I just added to only those 2 rests basic auth, so where should I store username and password for those basic auth services?

Comment: IMHO you should either ask the user to provide the username/pwd for basic auth or not use basic auth at all (as already said everyone willing to will be able to read username/pwd from javascript sources anyhow)

Comment: Yes. Either always ask for username/password so it's never stored or exchange it for a token so it's only asked once in a while. Username/password last forever and tokens can expire.

Comment: So in this case storing them in environment.prod.ts file will be fine? Since we are hardcoding them in frontend, eveyone can easly get them. So question is, should I hardcode basic auth anywhere or i should turn of basic auth on backend side? From my perspective maybe I should just hardcode them, I know that everyone can extract those data, but I will be still secure from random calls from some brute force attacks?